# How should I design social login for my react native app?

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, react-native, facebook-login, google-signin

I am trying to create a react native application which has support for google and facebook login. I am using spring boot as backend server by creating apis that will be used by logged in user.
How should I design the social login in react native and link that with api authentication?
Are there any framework like firebase or keycloak which can be helpful here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Auth0? Here's the website: https://auth0.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use OAuth on the backend and some react packages for your app such as react-google-login, react-facebook-login.

Comment: I know this but I don't have the clear understanding from the architecture point of view. How should I link the google/facebook login with my api authentication?